# How can I set two request-Id's within one wiremock (Performance testing)?

Tags: mocking, performance-testing, wiremock

I am writing a wiremock, we have a mock which has already been written by someone else and we want to be able to use this exact one, the problem is we want to be able to use our own requestId while not changing the requestId that was previously set by the person who wrote the wiremock - is there a way to add two requestId's to one wiremock?

Previously I have tried to use this way to add two request-Id's:

```
"request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPathPattern": "endpoint",
    "or": [
       {
         "headers": {
           "x-request-id": {
             "contains": "mock.*one.*"
           }
         },
        {
         "headers": {
           "x-request-id": {
             "contains": "mock.*two.*"
           }
         },
       }
     ]
}
```

However I get back an MappingFileException error

Is there some other way I would be able to achieve this?

Comment: maybe try to use regexp in id field? I don't know if it's possible

Comment: do you have an example of what that might look like?

Comment: https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

The correct nesting is request element->element key->matcher combinator (or)->matchers.

This should do the trick:

```
"request": {
  "method": "POST",
  "urlPath": "/endpoint",
  "headers": {
    "x-request-id": { 
      "or": [
        { "matches": "mock.*one.*" },
        { "matches": "mock.*two.*" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this out and attempted to test it through postman, but it seems it's unable to pick up the x-request-id :(

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: when run in postman with this x-request-id "mock.*one.*" it works if I change it to use the other x-request-id in the same postman request I'm making I get back a 422/ 500 status code